# uitabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wrote an app that uses `UITabBarController`, but if I add a lot of tabs it don't show me *more* button. Doesn't the `UITabBarController` creates this button automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create it manually. The "fifth tab is more" is just a convention. It's up to you to create a UIView/UIViewController pair to manage your additional settings and map them to that fifth tab.

Comment: there is any tutorial for this thing?

Comment: There's probably one out there somewhere, but if you know how to create the other four tab views, then you already know all there is to know. The "more" tab isn't special in any way. You create the view for that tab exactly as you do for all the other ones.

Comment: Is this still true in iOS 6? Because it contradicts what I'm reading in iOS 5/iOS 6 books.

Answer (score 1):

No - according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you should not need to handle this yourself.

> The tab bar has limited space for
>   displaying your custom items. If you add six or more custom view
>   controllers to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller displays
>   only the first four items plus the standard More item on the tab bar.
>   Tapping the More item brings up a standard interface for selecting the
>   remaining items.